# Move from cumulative incidence to survival probability

Tags: r, survival-analysis

In the context of Competing risk analyses, I plotted the following graph representing the cumulative incidence of death (=competing risk) over time by gender:

```
# CREATE THE SIMULATED DATASET 
# Set the sample size
n<- 8076
# CReate a variable for follow-up time
time<- c(rep(180,6533),sample(1:179,n-6533,replace = TRUE))
# Create a variable for status
status<-ifelse(time==180,0,1) # O= alive/censored
# 1 = death
# Create age
age<-sample(18:90,n,replace = TRUE)
# Create gender
sex<-sample(c("male","female"),n,replace = TRUE)
# Combine
df<-data.frame(time,status,age,sex)
df$sex<-as.factor(df$sex)

# Plot the cumulative incidence curve 
library(cmprsk)

cum<-cuminc(df$time,df$status,group = df$sex,cencode = 0)
```

[image: Cumulative incidence of death by gender]

Instead of having cumulative incidence of death, I would like to have the survival probability (1-cumulative incidence of death). To do this I used this code:

```
plot(cum, function(x) 1-x, main = "Survival Probability",xlab = "Survival proba",
     ylab = "Time in days")
```

But it doesn't work and I got the following error message:

```
Error in title(...) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Do you have an idea of how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The object of class `cuminc` is a list. The first two elements of the list are called `"female 1"` and `"male 1"`. Each of those are also lists with elements `time`, `est`, and `var`. The `est` element is the cumulative incidence of death. To get survival, you would take `1 - est`.

Output of `str(cum)`:

```
str(cum)
List of 3
 $ female 1:List of 3
  ..$ time: num [1:360] 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 ...
  ..$ est : num [1:360] 0 0 0.00126 0.00126 0.00302 ...
  ..$ var : num [1:360] 0.00 0.00 3.16e-07 3.16e-07 7.57e-07 ...
 $ male 1  :List of 3
  ..$ time: num [1:358] 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 ...
  ..$ est : num [1:358] 0 0 0.00146 0.00146 0.00341 ...
  ..$ var : num [1:358] 0.00 0.00 3.56e-07 3.56e-07 8.30e-07 ...
 $ Tests   : num [1, 1:3] 0.0789 0.7788 1
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "1"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "stat" "pv" "df"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "cuminc"
```

To plot the survival curves, create a copy of the `cum` object and modify the `est` elements for female and male, then plot it. (The `wh` argument is used to move the legend to a different location than the default upper left, which overlaps with the survival curves.)

```
surv <- cum
surv[['female 1']][['est']] <- 1 - surv[['female 1']][['est']]
surv[['male 1']][['est']] <- 1 - surv[['male 1']][['est']]

plot(surv, main = "Survival Probability",xlab = "Survival probability",
     ylab = "Time in days", wh = c(0, 0.15))
```

[image]

This solution is a little bit hacky and there may be better solutions available in the **cmprsk** package.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider accepting the answer (green check mark) if you think it is the correct answer, so it can better help others.